# How to get data from a table like wp_options

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The parameters of my website are saved in my database, in a table called "*jmc_options*", I was inspired by the organization of the table "*wp_options*" of Wordpress. **I don't use any CMS!**

```
option_id   option_name             option_value
1           siteurl                 http://localhost/jalertemacommune
2           home                    http://localhost/jalertemacommune
3           sitename                J'alerte ma Commune
4           sitedescription         La première communauté d'entraide entre habitants.
5           users_can_register      1
6           sitelogo                logo.png
7           maintenance_mode        0
8           maintenance_reason      Aucune information.
9           users_can_login         1
10          users_can_contact       1
11          users_can_submit        1
12          inactive_logout_time    900
13          zone_restriction        0
14          note                    Aucune information actuellement.
```

But I'm  facing a problem, how to exploit these data to display them on my website? So I'm trying to get the data from "*jmc_options*" and save them as constants.

Currently, I multiply this code for each of my entries in the "*jmc_options*" table.

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT option_value AS 'sitename' FROM jmc_options WHERE option_name = 'sitename';");
while ($data = $q->fetch())
{
    define('WEBSITE_NAME', $data['sitename']);
}
$q->closeCursor();
```

(I know this code is not necessarily correct).
I think there is definitely a cleaner way to do that, but I don't know how to do... Is it possible to have an example to simplify the process? I would like to retrieve all data from this table, and avoid doing a lot of queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the column `option_name` as the name of the constant and `option_value` as the value of the constant.

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM jmc_options;");
while ($data = $q->fetch())
{
    define(strtoupper($data['option_name']), $data['option_value']);
}
$q->closeCursor();
```

this will also enable you to add another variable to the table, and start using it immediately on your code.